# Stack Smashing Challenge

Tags: buffer-overflow

I know what I need to do in this challenge, but I am completely lost on how to do the first crucial step. What needs to happen is that I need to overwrite the global structure variable pin_len, which will then let me overflow user_pin in mask_with_pin(), and jump to get_shell(). I'm not sure at all how to overwrite pin_len, though. To my eye, it seems like the writer is limiting the input using fgets. I would just like a nudge in the right direction. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//
// Globals
//

#define MAX_FIELD_LEN 32
#define BUFFER_SIZE 64

struct scratch_space {
    char notepad[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned int pin_len;
} g_scratch_space;

//
// Code
//

// TODO: Give a shell to users with a special hash
void get_shell()
{
    system("/bin/sh");
}

void scramble()
{
    int i = 0;

    // Scramble the first name in the global notepad
    for (i = 0; g_scratch_space.notepad[i]; i++)
        g_scratch_space.notepad[i] ^= ((0x7 << i) & 0xff);

    // Tick past the null-delimiter ...
    i++;

    // Scramble the last name in global notepad
    while (g_scratch_space.notepad[i])
        g_scratch_space.notepad[i++] |= 0x42;
}

void mask_with_pin()
{
    char user_pin[MAX_FIELD_LEN];

    // Prompt the user for a PIN
    printf("Enter the PIN you wish to use: ");
    fgets(user_pin, g_scratch_space.pin_len, stdin);

    // Scramble the global notepad with the user's PIN
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        g_scratch_space.notepad[i] ^= user_pin[i % g_scratch_space.pin_len];
}

void initialize_scratch_space()
{
    // Initialize the notepad to all zero bytes
    memset(g_scratch_space.notepad, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (!g_scratch_space.pin_len) 
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the PIN you wish to use: ");
        g_scratch_space.pin_len = get_uint();
    }

    if (g_scratch_space.pin_len > MAX_FIELD_LEN - 1) 
    {
        printf("[!!] PIN Size exceeds maximum value, quitting...");
        exit(1);
    }

}

void interface() 
{
    char firstname[MAX_FIELD_LEN] = {};
    char lastname[MAX_FIELD_LEN] = {};
    char choice = 'y';

    unsigned int firstname_len = 0;
    unsigned int lastname_len = 0;

    // Initialize the scratchspace for the first time
    initialize_scratch_space();

    while (choice == 'y') 
    {

        // Zero out our local buffers
        memset(firstname, 0, MAX_FIELD_LEN);
        memset(lastname, 0, MAX_FIELD_LEN);

        // Get the user's first and last name. 
        printf("Enter your first name: ");
        fgets(firstname, MAX_FIELD_LEN, stdin);

        printf("Enter your last name: ");
        fgets(lastname, MAX_FIELD_LEN, stdin);

        // Get the length of the names
        firstname_len = strnlen(firstname, MAX_FIELD_LEN);
        lastname_len = strnlen(lastname, MAX_FIELD_LEN);

        // Copy their first name into the notepad
        memcpy(g_scratch_space.notepad, firstname, firstname_len);

        // Copy their last name into the notepad, placing it after the first name
        memcpy(&g_scratch_space.notepad[++firstname_len], lastname, lastname_len);

        // Scramble the input
        scramble(); 

        // Check if the user wants to further scramble their hash
        printf("Apply PIN Scrambling? [y/n] ");
        choice = get_char();

        // Apply final scramble (if applicable), and print the resulting hash
        if (choice == 'y') 
        {
            mask_with_pin();
            print_hash(BUFFER_SIZE, g_scratch_space.notepad);
            initialize_scratch_space();
        }
        else if (choice == 'n')
        {
            print_hash(BUFFER_SIZE, g_scratch_space.notepad);
            initialize_scratch_space();
        }

        // Allow the user to stop generating hashes
        printf("Continue generating hashes? [y/n] ");
        choice = get_char();
    }
}

void main() 
{
    init_wargame();

    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("--[ Stack Smashing Level #2 - SecureHash                    \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    interface();

    // Exit the program / return from main
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just completed this challenge; it's part of the *Fundamentals of Software Exploitation* training course provided by [RET2 Systems](https://wargames.ret2.systems/course). I can't find a policy on the RET2 website WRT posting solutions online, so I'm only going provide hints here for anyone that might want help with this in the future.

Consider the following:

- The `notepad` buffer is initialized to all zeroes by `initialize_scratch_space()`.
- `firstname` and `lastname` are copied into the `notepad` buffer contiguously. Due to the buffer initialization and general program behavior, the two strings are separated by a null byte.
- Since the two strings are copied contiguously, the separating null byte will be in a different location depending on the length of `firstname`.
- The null byte is *not* set during the copying of the name strings. Rather, it's set during the zeroing of the buffer during initialization.

With all this in mind, what would happen if:

- There was some way to bypass the zeroing of the buffer between the creation of two hashes, and
- The `firstname` input string was a different length between two hash creation operations?

I believe this line of questioning should be useful for figuring out the solution.